# c programming segfault unitialised int?

Tags: c, gcc, initialization, segmentation-fault

I have this c program that looks like.

```
int indexLength;
char *args[1024];
while(args[indexLength])
     indexLength++;
```

If i run the program under computer at work, the while loop line gives me a segfault..and the indexLength take some ridiculous arbitrary value.
But if i run the program on a linux machine at home, there are no segfault and my program run normally.

The only difference i can think of between the 2 machine is that the one at work has gcc4.7 redhat version, and is running Fedora OS, and my machine at home has gcc4.7 downloaded from ppa repository, and is running ubuntu OS.
But, i'm not convinced that's the only difference! What can it be?

EDIT: sorry i forgot to mention. The segfault went away on the computer at work if i initialise indexLength = 0..

Comment: see undefined behavior: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: the initial value of indexLength is unknown, so it's impossible to answer this question

Comment: `indexLength` will have an indeterminate value, possibly beyond the bounds of the array `args`.

Comment: You probably assume a default initialization with 0 or NULL. While that is guaranteed for variables with *static storage duration*, this is wrong for *automatic* variables; their value is indeterminate and using such a value invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from uninitialized memory is undefined behavior. Variables are not initialized by default, so `indexLength` can take any value until you assign it. Since the behavior is undefined, the program could run on some machines, and crash on others.

Moreover, even initializing the `indexLength` to zero does not fix undefined behavior, because `args` remains uninitialized. This means that the program may not stop upon reaching the end of the array, and access values past the end of the allocated region. Of course in order to do that all values in the array of 1024 items must be non-zero, so the odds are in favor of stopping before reaching the end of the array. However, in order to fix this undefined behavior you need to check the index before accessing values.

Comment: @ImNoob Yes, it's undefined behavior: you can detect it using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: forgive me if this sounds silly. Why some machine runs code with undefined behaviour, but some not?

Comment: @ImNoob They both run code with undefined behavior, it's just that one happens to crash, while the other one does not crash. It is perfectly acceptable for code with undefined behavior to not crash. In fact, I am willing to bet that a lot of software out there in everyday use contain code with undefined behavior of one sort or the other. It is a lot harder to detect undefined behavior in complex programs precisely because it may appear to run just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour

- `args` is uninitialised so each element contains unpredictable values.  Maybe you'll find a NULL pointer in the next 4k of stack and exit the loop; maybe you won't and you'll read beyond the end of the array
- `indexLength` is uninitialised so you may read way beyond the end of your array immediately
- the effect of reading beyond the end of `args` is also unpredictable.  This includes potentially crashing, say if you don't find a zero word before you reach the limits of readable memory for your process

Despite initial appearances, setting `indexLength=0` didn't actually make your code safe.  You're still reading uninitialised memory so are relying on finding a NULL element inside `args`.  There is no way to guarantee that you'll find this.  If your loop doesn't exit before you reach the end of your array, you're back into undefined behaviour so your program may crash on any further iteration.